# forEach works at getElementsByName but not for getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me why this works:

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
quantity.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('change',(function() {myFunction();})));
```

But this not:

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
quantity.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('change',(function() {myFunction();})));
```

Is the output-format different? What i have to change to get the same result. running a function when an input field with the class "quantity" is changed?...

Comment: What HTML is this operating on? How are you determining it "doesn't work"? Provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Look at the documentation. [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) vs [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns a NodeList, and NodeLists do have a `forEach` method on them.

In contrast, `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, and HTMLCollections do *not* have a `forEach` method on them.

They're both quite similar sorts of array-like collections in other respects.

Both methods can be iterated over with `for..of`, if you want:

```
for (const quantity of document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")) {
  quantity.addEventListener('change', myFunction);
}
```

Rather than memorizing all the differences, I prefer to always use `querySelectorAll`, since it returns a static (more predictable) NodeList (and so has `forEach`) which is also much more flexible than any of the other selection methods (since it can accept any selector string).

Answer (score -1):

Try

`Array.from(quantity).forEach(item => item.addEventListener('change',(function() {myFunction();})));`

**document.getElementsByName** returns a **NodeList []** which is iterable as an array while getElementsByClassname returns an **HTMLCollection []** which is not. 
Use Array.from to convert it to an array